# Selling Partner API Amazon 400 bad request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, amazonsellercentral

I am trying to make an API call to Amazon's selling partner API documented here - [SP-API](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs) .
I make a call through Java API specifically to OrdersV0API as follows -

```
 GetOrdersResponse resp = apiInstance.getOrders(marketPlaceIds, createdAfter, createdBefore,
                        lastUpdatedAfter, lastUpdatedBefore, orderStatuses, fulfillmentChannels, paymentMethods, buyerEmail,
                        sellerOrderId, maxResultsPerPage, easyShipShipmentStatuses, nextToken, amazonOrderIds);
```

However, despite trying multiple inputs , I am getting the following -

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders?CreatedAfter=2021-01-07T00%3A11%3A12.515020&CreatedBefore=2021-01-07T00%3A11%3A12.515060&LastUpdatedAfter=2021-01-07T00%3A11%3A12.515020&LastUpdatedBefore=2021-01-07T00%3A11%3A12.515060&BuyerEmail=&SellerOrderId=&MaxResultsPerPage=1&NextToken=&OrderStatuses=Unshipped&MarketplaceIds=A21TJRUUN4KGV&FulfillmentChannels=MFN&PaymentMethods=Other}
```

The documentation by Amazon is not the best in the world and so I am looking to get a solution from the community. Wondering if anyone has been in similar shoes ?

Comment: BadRequest means something about your params is invalid. Since it looks like all params are optional I would start with one param and test adding them one by one until you find the one that fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If look at the request you are sending. There are no values for some params, but still the keys are present, like this part `BuyerEmail=&SellerOrderId`

Answer (score 7):

I've got the same problem/error `400 Bad Request` when making an Orders Call to Amazon Selling Partner API. But the reason was because [Amazon Authentication](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api#step-3-add-headers-to-the-uri) `host` header was like full [endpoint url](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/sp-api-endpoints) with `https://`, but **has to be without the one**, for example, `sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com`

Comment: This was exactly the issue for me - thanks!

Comment: Holy jesus, you just saved me sinking hours more into this issue. Thank you,.